# Problem with External Link in Apex:output link

Tags: visualforce

I am using the below syntax to get the url .
Note - I have to use string functions left, mid and find here as my controller 
is returning value like this :

Google | https://www.gooogle.com

in URL string from where I am getting the website name and URL both in a single variable seperate by a pipe character.

```
<apex:outputlink value="javascript:window.open('{!mid(url,find('|', url),len(url))}','_blank')">
    {!left(url,(find('|', url)-1))}
</apex:outputlink>
```

but the URL output  is coming like this -

https://ap13.visual.force.com/apex/%7Chttps://www.google.com/

my desired output is - https://www.google.com/

Please suggest how to get rid of the part - https://ap13.visual.force.com/apex/%7 
before the actual URL .

Comment: Its probably there is a space in your URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add one to your index in the `MID` function. Note that `%7C` is the encoded value of the pipe character  (`|`). You should also `TRIM` the result, so it will work whether or not there are spaces around the pipe character. I would also recommend you not use Javascript for this functionality, simply add a `target` attribute. Here is a page that does work and demonstrates the minor tweaks you should make:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:variable var="url" value="Google | https://www.google.com" />
    <apex:outputlink value="{!MID(url, FIND('|', url) + 1, LEN(url))}" target="_blank">
        {!LEFT(url,(FIND('|', url)-1))}
    </apex:outputlink>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your url paramter is probably www.google.com, while it should be 
http://www.google.com

[Redirecting to external site from the value from url field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/60590/redirecting-to-external-site-from-the-value-from-url-field)